# json-schema, array of object, unique key-value

Tags: jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I have the following schema

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "choices": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "value": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "isCorrect": {
            "type": "boolean"
          }
        },
        "required": ["value", "isCorrect"],
        "additionalProperties": false
      },
      "minItems": 1,
      "maxItems": 50,
      "uniqueItems": true,
      "additionalItems": false,
    }
  }
}
```

Which validates data

```json
{
  "choices": [
    {
      "value": "John",
      "isCorrect": true
    },
    {
      "value": "Doe",
      "isCorrect": true
    }
  ] 
}
```

But I want `isCorrect` to have a single `true` (others `false`) in the array of the objects.

Is it possible to validate the uniqueness on a single key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't check uniqueness based on a key, but you can use a combination of `contains` and `maxContains` to have the constraint you described.

In the `properties.choices` object, add the following...

```json
      "contains": {
        "properties": {
          "isCorrect": {
            "const": true
          }
        }
      },
      "maxContains": 1,
```

You can check this using https://json-schema.hyperjump.io

The `contains` keyword makes sure that the array contains at least one item that is valid according to the subschema value.

The `maxContains` keyword, if the `contains` keyword is used, makes sure no more that number of items are valid according to the `contains` subschema value.

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-bhutton-json-schema-validation-00#section-6.4.4